# error in getline input in c++

Tags: c++, getline

Hi guys i am facing an unknown error while taking input from getline.My purpose is to take a number and two strings as input from the user and print the first string.Here is the problem code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int t;
  cin>>t;
  while(t--)
   {    string s,p;
        getline(cin,s);
        getline(cin,p);
        cout<<s;
   }
  return 0;
  }
```

Now when i give input like:

```
1
abababa abb
b
```

it doesn’t print anything.Why is it happening?

Comment: Why are yiu using a `while` here?

Comment: Because he wants to run the loop t times. Why shouldn't he?

Comment: @AdrianMay `My purpose is to take a number and two strings as input from the user and print the first string.`

Comment: actually my original code is totally different i have just written this code to show you the problem that i was facing while taking input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After `cin>>t`, there is a newline remaining in the stream, then the newline will be assigned to `s`, so `cout<<s` seems to print nothing(Actually, it prints a newline).
 add `cin.ignore(100, '\n');` before first `getline` to ingore the newline.

Comment: it means maximum number of characters to extract (and ignore). You can also use other numbers:)

Answer (score 1):

Each time you use cin to get something like in `cin >> t`, it will leave a newline in the input buffer. so in next operation it will be affected by that and will seem to skip the "wait for return key" and hence abnormality. To avoid that use`cin::ignore`.

the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) says:

> Extracts characters from the input sequence and discards them, until
>   either n characters have been extracted, or one compares equal to
>   delim.
>
> The function also stops extracting characters if the end-of-file is
>   reached. If this is reached prematurely (before either extracting n
>   characters or finding delim), the function sets the eofbit flag.

I have written your code in very understandable way but working
Let me know if you have any issue

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int t=0;
 cout<<"Enter t\n";
  cin>>t;
  cin.ignore(); 
  while(t>0)
   {    string s,p;
        cout<<"Enter s\n";
        getline(cin,s);
        cout<<"Enter p\n";
        getline(cin,p);
        cout<<" Values s:"<<s<<" p:"<<p<<"\n";
        t--;
   }
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: hahaha! People at SO are very fast. You gotta love SO!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because getline() doesn't ignore the new line ccharacter, but it reads it in the next call yo getline. Try yo put a getline() before each calle, something like this:

```
Int main() {
int t;
cin>>t;

string s,p;

getline(cin,s);

while(t--)
{  
    getline(cin,s);
    getline(cin, p);
    getline(cin,p);
    cout<<s;
 }
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The newline from `cin >> t;` after pressing enter is still in std::cin when `getline(cin,s)` is called, resulting in s being empty. The string you enter is actually being stored in p. Try using a different capture method or flushing the cin buffer before using it again.