# Using getline() in array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, getline

Today,I was making one program,basically it takes routes of cities you have visited in past,and at the end it should return a whole route of your trip,routes.

In first line you're entering number number of cities you visited in past(including your home city), `N`.

Let's assume that our home city is Paris. In second line you enter your home town (`Paris` in our case).

In next `N` lines you enter your trip routes, they don't need to be in order as you did them, so they can be in any order:

Input:

```
4  
Paris  
Berlin-Paris  
Paris-Zagreb  
Ljubljana-Berlin   
Zagreb-Ljubljana
```

Output:

```
Paris-Zagreb-Ljubljana-Berlin-Paris
```

This is my code written in c++ :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string s[1000],city;
int n;  

int main(){
    cin>>n;
    cin>>city;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>s[i];
    }
    cout<<city;
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(s[i].substr(0,city.length())==city){
                city=s[i].substr(city.length()+1);
            cout<<"-"<<city;
            s[i]='\0';
            }   
        }   
    }


}
```

It's not the most efficient way to do it,I know...And it only work with single word cities(doesn't work for New York and other 2+ worded cities)

**Now my question is,is there a simple way to do it with 2+ worded cities,like New York?**
I tried using getline(cin,city) and getline(cin,s[i]),but it's not working for some reason,maybe I didn't do it correctly.

While trying with `getline()` I noticed that when I tried to input string s[i] with `getline()` my loop `for(int i=0;i<n;i++)` only went to n-1,I mean I couldn't enter n strings in that array
For example if I used N=5,I could only enter 4 strings

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    getline(cin,s[i]);
}
```

Let's me input 4 strings,while

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    cin>>s[i];
}
```

Let's me input 5 strings

---

Also I noticed that if I have some simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string city;
int n;  

int main(){
    cin>>n;
    getline(cin,city);
    cout<<city;
}
```

I thought that it should output name of the city,but that isn't a case, can somebody explain why?

Maybe I was missing something,that's it...
Thanks for reading,if you know the answer please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

> Now my question is,is there a simple way to do it with 2+ worded cities,like New York?

Yes, this should have the same effect, but allows 2+ word cities:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string s[1000],city;
int n;  

int main(){
    string nStr;
    getline(cin, nStr);
    // converting string input to an integer
    n = stoi(nStr);
    getline(cin, city);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        getline(cin, s[i]);
    }
    cout<<city;
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(s[i].substr(0,city.length())==city){
                city=s[i].substr(city.length()+1);
            cout<<"-"<<city;
            s[i]='\0';
            }   
        }   
    }
}
```

Input:
5
Paris
Berlin-New York
Paris-Zagreb
Ljubljana-Berlin
Zagreb-Ljubljana
New York-Paris

Output:
Paris-Zagreb-Ljubljana-Berlin-New York-Paris

> I thought that it should output name of the city,but that isn't a
>   case, can somebody explain why?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26466469/9238288) answer explains cin is placing a newline character in the stream which getline immediately reads in to `city` and prints a newline and so looks like nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a simple way to do it with 2+ worded cities, like New York?

*Answer:* Yes.

As noted in the answer by [@jackw11111](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9238288/jackw11111), your problem in reading names containing *whitespace* was due to `std::cin` that reads only from the beginning of the line up to the first *whitespace*. So for example attempting to read `"New York"` with `std::cin >> city;` would result in `city` containing `"New"` while `"York"` remains in `stdin` unread.

The solution is to use `getline`, which will read up until the delimiter character specified (default: `'\n'`).

Now, for the remainder of your problem, reading trip legs with two (or more) cities separated by `'-'`, there are a number of ways you can approach the problem. Since each leg of a trip will include a *from* and *to* city, using [std::pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) provided as part of the STL `utility` header would provide a convenient way to store related *from* and *to* cities. You can then use a [`std::vector<std::pair<..,..>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to create a *vector-of-pairs*.

Unless you absolutely are required to read the first integer value for the number of trips taken -- you can do away with it as it isn't really needed to handle the input. In reality all you need is your `home` city and then you can read as many lines of input as you like and store as many trip *from* and *to* city pairs until `EOF` if reading from a file, or a blank line is entered to indicate end-of-input.

To separate lines read with `getline`, using a [std::stringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream). To read from the `std::stringstream`, you can use `getline` once again (with a delimiter of `'-'`) to separate the *from-to* cities in the line. Placing the line in a stringstream and then reading from the stringstream prevents `getline` from skipping over the `'\n'` when the delimiter has been changed to something else.

So in your case you can declare the vector of pairs of strings along with a few additional strings to hold `home` and help with parsing and you can simply read the `home` city first, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main (void) {

    std::string home, last, trip, total;    /* strings */
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> vp {}; /* vector of pairs */

    std::cout << "enter home city: ";       /* prompt for home city */
    if (!getline (std::cin, home)) {        /* read/validate home city */
        std::cerr << "error: failed to read home-city.\n";
        return 1;
    }
```

Now just loop reading lines of input and checking if the line is empty to indicate end-of-input. Create a stringstream from each line and then read from the stringstream with `getline` (this eliminates the need of using `substr` to parse cities from the line). Add each pair of *from-to* cities to your vector using [std::make_pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair):

```
    /* prompt for trips (any number of legs per-line), ENTER alone when done */
    std::cout << "\nenter trips (format city1-city2[-cityN]) "
                    "[Enter] alone when done\n\ntrip: ";
    while (getline (std::cin, trip)) {      /* while trip entered */
        if (!trip.length())                 /* if empty (zero length) break */
            break;
        std::stringstream ss (trip);        /* create stringsteam from line */
        std::string from, to;               /* strings for from and to cities */
        if (getline (ss, from, '-')) {      /* get from city from stringstrem */
            while (getline (ss, to, '-')) { /* get to city from stringstream */
                vp.push_back(std::make_pair (from, to));  /* add pair to vector */
                from = to;                  /* update from = to */
            }
        }
        std::cout << "trip: ";              /* prompt for next trip */
    }
```

Finally, just loop over your stored pairs (with nested loops) to pick out all of the trip legs based on a *from-to* and then find the next by setting `from = to;` and finding the next match. (you can also add additional checks to make sure that a proper *from-to* is found on each iteration -- that is left to you -- something simple like `bool found;` will do)

```
    total = home;                           /* initialize total & last to home */
    last = home;
    for (auto t1 : vp) {                    /* loop over each trip */
        for (auto t2 : vp) {                /* 2nd search loop */
            if (t2.first == last) {         /* find trip begins with last city */
                total += "-" + t2.second;   /* add trip end to total */
                last = t2.second;           /* update last to end */
                break;                      /* go find next trip */
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << '\n' << total << '\n';     /* output total trip beg to end */
```

(**note:** the first object in each `std::pair` is accessed using `.first` and the second using `.second` -- even somewhat logical...)

There are many variation your can come up with. Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main (void) {

    std::string home, last, trip, total;    /* strings */
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> vp {}; /* vector of pairs */

    std::cout << "enter home city: ";       /* prompt for home city */
    if (!getline (std::cin, home)) {        /* read/validate home city */
        std::cerr << "error: failed to read home-city.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    /* prompt for trips (any number of legs per-line), ENTER alone when done */
    std::cout << "\nenter trips (format city1-city2[-cityN]) "
                    "[Enter] alone when done\n\ntrip: ";
    while (getline (std::cin, trip)) {      /* while trip entered */
        if (!trip.length())                 /* if empty (zero length) break */
            break;
        std::stringstream ss (trip);        /* create stringsteam from line */
        std::string from, to;               /* strings for from and to cities */
        if (getline (ss, from, '-')) {      /* get from city from stringstrem */
            while (getline (ss, to, '-')) { /* get to city from stringstream */
                vp.push_back(std::make_pair (from, to));  /* add pair to vector */
                from = to;                  /* update from = to */
            }
        }
        std::cout << "trip: ";              /* prompt for next trip */
    }

    total = home;                           /* initialize total & last to home */
    last = home;
    for (auto t1 : vp) {                    /* loop over each trip */
        for (auto t2 : vp) {                /* 2nd search loop */
            if (t2.first == last) {         /* find trip begins with last city */
                total += "-" + t2.second;   /* add trip end to total */
                last = t2.second;           /* update last to end */
                break;                      /* go find next trip */
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << '\n' << total << '\n';     /* output total trip beg to end */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/triptotal
enter home city: Paris

enter trips (format city1-city2[-cityN]) [Enter] alone when done

trip: Berlin-Paris
trip: Paris-New York
trip: New York-Zagreb
trip: Ljubljana-Berlin
trip: Zagreb-Ljubljana
trip:

Paris-New York-Zagreb-Ljubljana-Berlin-Paris
```

That could also be entered as:

```
$ ./bin/triptotal
enter home city: Paris

enter trips (format city1-city2[-cityN]) [Enter] alone when done

trip: San Antonio-New York-Berlin-Paris
trip: Paris-Frankfort-Zagreb
trip: Zagreb-Ljubljana-Dallas
trip: Dallas-San Antonio
trip:

Paris-Frankfort-Zagreb-Ljubljana-Dallas-San Antonio-New York-Berlin-Paris
```

The one additional task you will have is finding a way to handle multiple trip legs that may visit the same city. (that too is left for you) Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.